ROS melodic, rf2o, Baseodom and navigation error
I am currently using ROS1 Melodic. I am trying to navigate a Husky vehicle equipped with a Velodyne VLP16 and a RealSense D435i, using move_base. I have two launch codes, as outlined below.
first launch file : huskrealvel.launch
<!--launch file name = huskyrealvel.launch-->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

  <arg name="world_name" default="worlds/husky_empty.world"/>
  <arg name="model" default="husky"/>
  <!--arg name="rviz" default="False"/-->
 
  <include file="$(find gazebo_ros)/launch/empty_world.launch">
    <arg name="world_name" value="$(arg world_name)"/>
    <arg name="paused" value="false"/>
    <arg name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>
    <arg name="gui" value="true"/>
    <arg name="headless" value="false"/>
    <arg name="debug" value="true"/>
    <arg name="verbose" default="false"/>
  </include>

  <include file="$(find husky_gazebo)/launch/spawn_husky.launch">
  </include>

  <include file="$(find velodyne_pointcloud)/launch/VLP16_points.launch">
  </include>

  <include file="$(find pointcloud_to_laserscan)/launch/point_to_scan.launch">
  </include>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
        args="0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 base_link velodyne 100"/>

  <node pkg="rf2o_laser_odometry" type="rf2o_laser_odometry_node" name="rf2o_laser_odometry" output="screen">
    <param name="laser_scan_topic" value="/laser/scan"/>
    <param name="odom_topic" value="/odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame_id" value="base_footprint"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id" value="odom"/>
    <param name="publish_tf" value="true"/>
    <param name="init_pose_from_topic" value=""/>
    <param name="freq" value="10.0"/>
    <param name="verbose" value="true"/>
  </node>

</launch>

point_to_scan.launch file :
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<launch>
    <!-- Run pointcloud_to_laserscan node -->
    <node pkg="pointcloud_to_laserscan" type="pointcloud_to_laserscan_node" name="pointcloud_to_laserscan">
        <remap from="cloud_in" to="/velodyne_points"/>
        <remap from="scan" to="/laser/scan"/>
        
        <param name="transform_tolerance" value="0.01" />
        <param name="min_height" value="-0.4" />
        <param name="max_height" value="1" />
        <param name="angle_min" value="-3.1415926" />
        <param name="angle_max" value="3.1415926" />
        <param name="angle_increment" value="0.007" />
        <param name="scan_time" value="0.1" />
        <param name="range_min" value="0.2" />
        <param name="range_max" value="100" />
        <param name="use_inf" value="true" />
        <param name="inf_epsilon" value="1.0" />
        <param name="concurrency_level" value="1" />
    </node>
</launch>

second launch file : navigation.launch
<?xml version="1"?>
<!-- 
  Simulate a carlike robot with the teb_local_planner in stage:
  - stage
  - map_server 
  - move_base
  - static map
  - amcl
  - rviz view
 -->
<launch>

        <!--  ************** Navigation ***************  -->
  <node pkg="move_base" type="move_base" respawn="false" name="move_base" output="screen">
    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="global_costmap" />

    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/costmap_common_params.yaml" command="load" ns="local_costmap" />

    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/local_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/global_costmap_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/base_local_planner_params.yaml" command="load" />

    <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/4wd/move_base_params.yaml" command="load" />
  </node>


    <!--  ****** Maps *****  -->
 <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(find scout_description)/maps/gs02.yaml" output="screen">
     <!--  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="/home/nvidia/map/2.yaml" output="screen">-->
      <param name="frame_id" value="map"/>
    </node>

    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find scout_description)/param/amcl_params.yaml" command="load" />
            <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="0"/>
            <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="0"/>
        <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="0"/>

                <remap from="scan" to="/laser/scan"/>
    </node>


  <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
    <remap from="odom" to="/odom" />
    <remap from="joint_states" to="/joint_states" />
    <param name="publish_frequency" value="50.0" />
   </node>
 
   <node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher" output="screen">
    <param name="publish_frequency" value="50.0" />
  </node>

  <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="odom_to_base_link" args="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 odom base_link 100" />

  <!--  **************** Visualisation ****************  -->
  <node name="car_rviz" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find scout_description)/rviz/rviz_navigation.rviz">
  </node>
  <include file="$(find scout_bringup)/launch/scout_volecity_smoother.launch"/>
  <include file="$(find scout_base)/launch/scout_base.launch">
      <arg name="port_name" default="can0" />
      <arg name="simulated_robot" default="false" />
  </include>

</launch>

However, when I launch the code (huskyrealvel.launch) that runs Gazebo with rf2o and Baseodom, I get proper odom values initially. But when I insert a new world into Gazebo, the odom values keep increasing continuously.

Moreover, when I launch the navigation file based on this setup, I observe issues with the robot model and navigation, as seen in the video below.


I would be grateful if you could kindly provide some insight into the cause and suggest possible solutions.
Thank you very much.
